Expo 51 ios fastlane build problem: The following build commands failed: ▸ PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClimbingymHK-ffeezmatbbkmrwgumzrsdhnfacxm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ClimbingymHK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ClimbingymHK.build/Release-iphoneos/ClimbingymHK.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'ClimbingymHK' from project 'ClimbingymHK')
▸ (1 failure)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClimbingymHK-ffeezmatbbkmrwgumzrsdhnfacxm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ClimbingymHK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ClimbingymHK.build/Release-iphoneos/ClimbingymHK.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'ClimbingymHK' from project 'ClimbingymHK')
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65
+---------------------------------------+
|           Build environment           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version | 2.219.0                 |
| sdk         | iPhoneOS17.4.sdk        |
+-------------+-------------------------+
When I tried to bundle my files with eas build --platform ios, it shows that the images cannot be resolved everytime.
My eas.json and app.json :
(https://i.sstatic.net/jy7L5VVF.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/8otSaHTK.png)
solutions of bundling the image
